# Deleted Android SDK Tools by accident, now SDK Manager won't start

Tags: android, eclipse

I've been using the Android SDK release preview and saw today that the Original SDK Tools were
upgraded to a new version. Instead of installing the new version, I clicked on the preview tools and deleted the two packages. Now when I try to run the android sdk manager I get a popup in eclipse "Could not find folder 'tools' inside SDK 'C:\Users\Me\android-sdks\'. How do I get my sdk manager back?

Comment: Thanks, I originally had an image, but thought it wasn't needed and I deleted the question along with it. hahaha

Answer (score 3):

I would recomend to reinstall the Android SDK. http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Comment: I downloaded the bundle, extracted it but don't know how to install.

Comment: @EGHDK: The bundle doesn't install. It is just a ZIP of an Eclipse directory and SDK. Just run the `eclipse` from inside the Eclipse directory, and it will automatically use the SDK from the peer directory, based on my admittedly limited testing.

Answer (score 0):

Just download the latest SDK tools from Google and install them again.

Answer (score 0):

Running the eclipse.exe wasn't working (getting some jni error popup). I ended up going into my android-sdks directory on my computer, and took all the folders I downloaded from the .zip and just dragged and dropped them over and it ended up working.